# How to append an array to an input, wrapping each value in a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, append

I've got some checkboxes, and each time I check/uncheck them I'd like their values to be appended to a search box, with each value being wrapped in a span.

Here's what I've got so far:

right now I'm just adding the array to the value of the input each time the array changes:

```
updateInputBox = function(query) {
  var inputBox;
  inputBox = $("#searchBox")
  inputBox.val(checkboxes);
}
```

**See here: https://jsfiddle.net/g7n9zpow/**

I'm having trouble thinking of how to get the `<span>` around each value. I thought of iterating the array, and appending the values to the value of the input, but then I'd have to check first if the input is already blank.. and it gets messy. I thought this would be easy.

**EDIT**

turns out trying to put a `<span/>` into an input is dumb. I wanted it so that I could style each value like this:

[image]

Comment: You want to wrap them in a `<span>` within the input field? Why?

Comment: A text input can only contain text. You can't have spans around parts of that text.

Comment: you can just concatinate the span tags, https://jsfiddle.net/g7n9zpow/1/

Comment: cant you have it comma separated? I would think you can run another function on it later, whatever you gonna do with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, now I realised I can't have a span within a input field, I'll find another solution. @DarrenSweeney, I wanted the span so that I could style each value.

Comment: How should value be styled ?

Comment: @guest271314 see edit, I put a picture

Comment: @f7n See post; substituted `div` having `contenteditable` attribute for `input` , used `css` `:before` to fashion `"x"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `div` element with `contenteditable` attribute set , `button` elements ; use `$.map()` , `$.filter()` ; `css` `:before` to style `"x"`

```js
    var checkboxes = [],
      elems = $(":checkbox"),
      inputBox = $("#searchBox");

    updateInputBox = function(query) {
      inputBox.html(query);
    }

    elems.change(function() {
      checkboxes = $.map(elems.filter(":checked"), function(el, i) {
        return checkboxes.indexOf(el.value) < 0 
               && "<button>" + el.value + "</button>"
      });
      updateInputBox(checkboxes)
      console.log(checkboxes);
    });
```

```css
#searchBox {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 80%;
}
button:before {
  content: "x ";
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Tom Hanks" name="actorName">Tom Hanks</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Tim Allen" name="actorName">Tim Allen</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Don Rickles" name="actorName">Don Rickles</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Jim Varney" name="actorName">Jim Varney</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Wallace Shawn" name="actorName">Wallace Shawn</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Fantasy" name="genreName">Fantasy</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Comedy" name="genreName">Comedy</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Children" name="genreName">Children</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Animation" name="genreName">Animation</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Adventure" name="genreName">Adventure</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="USA" name="countryName">USA</label>
</div>
<div contenteditable id="searchBox"></div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g7n9zpow/11/

Comment: nice, but there is one bug: if you check tom hanks, and tim allen, then you un-check tim allen, it removes tom hanks instead of tim allen. what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following using `map()` function.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return '<span>' + this.value + '</span>'
    }).get().join('');

    $("#searchBox").val(checkboxes);
})
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g7n9zpow/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them in a `<span></span>` then push:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkboxes.push('<span>'+$this.val()+'</span>') // <-- here
    updateInputBox(checkboxes)
  } else {
    index = checkboxes.indexOf('<span>'+$this.val()+'</span>'); // <-- and here
    if (index > -1)
      checkboxes.splice(index, 1);
    updateInputBox(checkboxes)
  }
  return console.log(checkboxes);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7n9zpow/6/)